# NamedQuery causing EntityManager creation fail

Tags: java, ejb, persistence

I have created a class corresponding to a database table and is persisted as such. The class is used to store APNS tokens (Not that it matters to the question) and is as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ApnsToken")
@NamedQuery(name = "apnsToken.removeByToken", query = "DELETE FROM ApnsToken tok WHERE tok.Token = ?1")
public class ApnsToken implements Serializable {
    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1516719311585221856L;

    @TableGenerator(name = "ApnsTokenGen", table = "Sequences", pkColumnName = "BeanName", valueColumnName = "SeqNumber", initialValue = 1)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "ApnsTokenGen")
    @Column(name = "TokenID", nullable = false)
    private Long tokenId;

    @Column(name = "Token")
    private String Token;

    public ApnsToken() {
    }
}
```

The persistence.xml is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="unit-name" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>data-source</jta-data-source>

    <class>com.package.model.ApnsToken</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now, my problem is that when I am deploying the EAR, the EntityManager fails to be created, and I know it is the NamedQuery that causes the problem because when I comment it out everything works fine... Now I am pretty convinced that my mistake is a stupid one, but I have been searching over the web to see examples and everything looks fine to me.

The NamedQuery is supposed to delete entries with the Token specified as parameter.

I have tried both the NamedQuery in the code and one like this:

```
DELETE FROM ApnsToken tok WHERE tok.Token = :mTok
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: Injection failure; nested exception is: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory has not been created for PU : PuId=myapp-ear#common-1.0.1-WS-websphere.jar#myapp-repos
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory has not been created for PU : PuId=myapp-ear#common-1.0.1-WS-websphere.jar#myapp-repos
    at  com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getEntityManagerFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1369)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getEntityManagerPool(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1577)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEntityManager.<init>(JPATxEntityManager.java:156)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.getEntityManager(JPAComponentImpl.java:1053)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.JPAJndiLookupObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(JPAJndiLookupObjectFactory.java:151)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(InjectionBinding.java:659)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionTargetField.inject(InjectionTargetField.java:245)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionEngineImpl.inject(InjectionEngineImpl.java:620)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.StatelessBeanO.initialize(StatelessBeanO.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.CMStatelessBeanOFactory.create(CMStatelessBeanOFactory.java:45)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createBeanO(EJSHome.java:1031)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createBeanO(EJSHome.java:1141)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.UncachedActivationStrategy.atActivate(UncachedActivationStrategy.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.Activator.activateBean(Activator.java:599)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.preInvokeActivate(EJSContainer.java:3964)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.EjbPreInvoke(EJSContainer.java:3349)
    at com.package.repos.EJSLocal1SLRepositoryDao_3de24cf0.putApnsToken(EJSLocal1SLRepositoryDao_3de24cf0.java)
```

Like I said, if I remove the NamedQuery the EntityManager is created successfully and I can persist, find and remove entries from the database without a problem. Any help or pointer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't answer your question directly, but jpa's entity manager has built in functionality to remove an entity based on an id, by using entityManager.find() and entityManager.remove(), so no need for a named query.

Comment: The problem is I won't have direct access to the ID, only the token contained in the entry. That's why I need the NamedQuery

Comment: Ok, try this "DELETE tok FROM ApnsToken tok WHERE tok.Token = :id" I think you may need 'tok' in between delete and from

Comment: Okay, so I just tried this and it does the exact same thing and before :/

Comment: Well it seems it was a stupid mistake after all, you can't see it here because I modified the code but the mistake is that in que query I putted the name of the Table and not the name of the class. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
"DELETE FROM ApnsToken tok WHERE tok.Token = ?1"
```

try

```
"DELETE FROM ApnsToken tok WHERE tok.Token = :someVariable"
```

Comment: forgot to mention I tried this already, without any success, i'll add it to my question.